# How to replace href of anchor tags with array of links?

Tags: javascript

// I am trying to replace href with array of links

```
    var link = ['replaceLink1', 'replaceLink2'];
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
    for(var i = 0; i < link.length; i++){
      for(var j = 0; j < links.length; j++){
        links[j].setAttribute('href',link[i]);
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to loops just remove one and use the iterator to go throw both arrays

```js
var link = ['replaceLink1', 'replaceLink2'];
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for (var i = 0; i < link.length; i++) {
    links[i].setAttribute('href', link[i]);
  }
```

```html
<a href="/link1" > click me ! </a>
<a href="/link2" >click me ! </a>
```

Comment: Thank you! That is amazing.

Answer (score 0):

you can loop with `for of` loop each anchor tag in the page and replace the `href` attribute with the corresponding link from an array (that have to be the same size as all the links on the page otherwise you'll get undefined as a link) like so:

```js
var linksToReplace = ['replaceLink1', 'replaceLink2'];
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');

for (let [i, link] of links.entries()) {
  link.setAttribute('href', linksToReplace[i]);
}
```

```html
<a href="/link1"> click me ! </a>
<a href="/link2">click me ! </a>
```